# Missing a CSS3 property. What is it?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

There's a simple CSS 3 hack to append `&nbsp;` to a div's contents, to prevent it from height-collapsing regardless of whether it contains text or not. I just can't find it again.

Where is it?

`<div></div> <!-- nothing in it = will collapse -->`

`<div>&nbsp;</div> <!-- still nothing in it but with &nbsp; appended it won't collapse -->`

`<div>SOME CONTENT&nbsp;</div> <!-- "SOME CONTENT" is added via JS; -->`

Comment: I believe you're looking for something like `div:after { content: " " }` but Kolink's answer is a much better and more compatible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be talking about `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements and the `content` property.

```
#someId:after {
    content: '&nbsp;';
}
```

But why not to use `min-height` as Kolink suggested?

As pointed in the comments, this appends as text, so the solution is to use the Unicode representation as a escaped sequence:

```
#someId:after {
    content: '\0000a0';
}
```

Comment: This will actually append the string `&nbsp;` to the end. CSS-appended text is not processed as HTML, so HTML entities do not get processed either.

Comment: You're right, but it shows how to do it, no? Just have to change it to a escaped unicode char: `\0000a0`

Comment: Font size is dynamically computed and it might gap upwards. Also your solution causes the string literal '&nbsp;' to appear, at least it does so on Opera.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL Updated my answer with the comment I've maded.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not allow you to just add content to HTML tags. That would be just wrong.

However, you can do this:

```
min-height: 1em;
```

This will ensure that the `div` is always at least one line tall, therefore not collapsing when there is no content.

Comment: I'm reluctant to upvote this because of the first sentence. :x

Comment: Also, 1em is the width of the m glyph in the current font-size. If your line-height is set to 1em, it will be equal to "one line tall", otherwise, it's just setting the minimum height to the width of the m.